# Mongoose: Populating with projection using attribute of scheme

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate

I triying the following **population/projection** and work fine

```
  modelBaby.findOne({'userId': req.user.data._id, '_id': req.params.id})
  .populate('categories._categoryId', {
    levels:{
      $elemMatch:{
        name: 'PURPLE'
      }
    }
  })
```

But i need name as a variable something like:

```
modelBaby.findOne({'userId': req.user.data._id, '_id': req.params.id})
      .populate('categories._categoryId', {
        levels:{
          $elemMatch:{
            // over heree !!
            name: 'categories._levelName' or this._levelName
          }
        }
      })
```

the scheme ref is

```
const babyCategory = new mongoose.Schema(
      {
        answer: {type: String},
        _categoryId: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, required: true, ref: 'category'},
        _categoryName: {type: String, required: true},
        _levelName: {type: String, required: true}
      },
      {versionKey: false, _id : false}
    );
```